# Application loading in Eclipse and studio

Tags: android, eclipse, qr-code

I have developed Qr scanner using zxing library. I run it Eclipse its working fine but i can't run it in studio after adding zxing on it. What would be the reason of this issue. Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue ? can you post something about issue ?

Comment: the reason is that you are doing something wrong. Since you didn't specify, which error you are getting, that is all help you can get from us.

Comment: error shown that new framework detected click to configure. on clicking none of files load